# jQuery value not getting assigned from ipinfo when expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I'm using:

```
//function to obtain current location, this is used to display relevant contact information
    $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response){
        $("#address").html(response.region);//http://jsfiddle.net/zK5FN/2/

        $("input[id=address]").val(response.region);

    }, "jsonp");
```

to get my current location for my contact page.  The aim is that I can use an if address== to display various contact numbers etc.

This function updates the value of a hidden field.  I've checked the debugger and it's working fine.

I'd then like to get the value so that I can play with it but it's always blank or empty.

I have

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var testLoc = $('#address').val();

            if(testLoc == ""){
                alert("NOES!!!");
            }

        });
```

which I've currently placed in the same script block within the head to see if the results are different, again, it's always blank and always returns the NOES alert.

I though that by waiting for the document to load I'd be certain that the values would be assigned/set.

Can anyone suggest a solution please?  I'm sure there's a simple fix and it's killing me

EDIT: HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name="address" id="address"/>
```

EDIT WITH SOLUTION:

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({url:"http://ipinfo.io",dataType:'jsonp'})
            .success(function(response){
                $("#address").val(response.region);
                $("input[id=address]").val(response.region);


                var testLoc = $('#address').val();
                if(testLoc == ""){
                    alert("NOES!!!");
                }else{
                    alert("jQuery can suck my...")
                }
            });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend putting your `$.get` request INSIDE the document.ready function.

Note that the ready function is called as soon as the DOM is ready, so even if the AJAX returns before then, the element that you're filling with the value may not even be ready.

```
$(function() { // this is shorthand for $(document).ready(
    $.get({url"http://ipinfo.io",dataType:'jsonp'})
    succsss(function(response){
        // do something with response
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v6DBB/

Comment: i still ge tthe same result

Comment: I've updated the code. Forgot that in order to connect to a different domain, you'll need to use jsonp

Answer (score 0):

You can't check the address until after get() returns:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
        $("#address").html(response.region); //http://jsfiddle.net/zK5FN/2/
        $("input[id=address]").val(response.region);
        var testLoc = $('#address').val();
        if (testLoc == "") {
            alert("NOES!!!");
        }
    }, "jsonp");
});
```

That said, when I run this the response.region is null so I still get the alert.

Comment: same here,. never returns the value -.-

Comment: Do you maybe want response.ip instead of response.region?